# MySQL, DROP TABLE generates a thread locking itself?

Tags: mysql, locking

I'm trying to drop a table on a local mysql instance, and the `DROP` statement (`DROP TABLE wqs_info`) hangs out forever...

Looking at mysql logs, I see the lock dumps:

```
--Thread 18692 has waited at btr0cur.cc line 1870 for 241.00 seconds the semaphore:
X-lock (wait_ex) on RW-latch at 00000194D3745E88 created in file buf0buf.cc line 1460
a writer (thread id 18692) has reserved it in mode  wait exclusive
number of readers 1, waiters flag 1, lock_word: efffffff
Last time read locked in file row0row.cc line 989
Last time write locked in file g:\ade\build\sb_0-26514852-1514435511.83\mysql-5.7.21\storage\innobase\include\mtr0mtr.ic line 117
```

What's strange here is that thread 18692 (a mysqld thread) is waiting for a lock that it's already owning?! How can this be possible?

(after 4-5 server restarts, I finally managed to drop the table, but I want to know how it's possible for a thread to wait for a lock itself owns?!)

Comment: What version of mysql?

Comment: @RickJames 5.7.21 (on windows)